# to have something to do with

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

1. A has something to do with B
2. B has something to do with A

Are #1 and #2 interchangeable?
I mean, is #1 equal to #2 or is there a difference? If there's a difference then what is the difference?

Comment: Have you looked up the phrase "has something to do with"?  That might be a good place to start...does it mean they're the same?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I looked and it says "used for saying that something is related to something else,". Then #1 = #2. But I'm not sure

Comment: Implication and logic are not really the same thing. That said, if A has to do with B, then, B could not not have something to do with A. A implies B, does not mean: B implies A, in logic.

Answer (score 1):

AS [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-have-something-to-do-with-sth) says, be/have something to do with something is ill-defined:

> *be/have something to do with something* informal ​
>
> C1 to be related to something **or** a cause of something but not in a
>   way that you know about or understand exactly:
>
> *I'm not sure what he does exactly - it's something to do with finance.*

(ie *is related to finance*. Here, 'finance has something to do with what he does' doesn't sound idiomatic. Probably because 'finance' is the wider field, 'what he does' a small part or small overlapping area. But with 'equivalents', like 'locks have something to do with keys', the A and B are reversible.)

..........

> It [the fact that it is brittle] might have something to do with the way it's made.

(ie It might be something that results from how it's made.)

In this case, 'The way it's made might have something to do with it being so brittle' (the reverse causative; CED does not give the 'or be caused by something' sense) seems to work.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it does not imply #1 = #2, am I understanding your answer correctly?

Comment: Leaving aside other more subtle restrictions on usage, CED says that 'A has something to do with B' can mean either 'A and B are related' '_or_' the more specific 'A is in a causal relationship with B' (which is obviously a hyponymic sense). I've added that I consider 'B is in a causal relationship with A' to be not an unidiomatic usage, in some contexts. // Although 'is related to' is a commutative relation, idiomaticity arguably doesn't allow 'Finance has something to do with what he does' from 'What he does has something to do with finance'. Which is the bigger field also seems important.

Answer (score 0):

1) Implication in logic is one thing; a way two things relate to each other, the relationship they have to each other:

In logic, if A → B, that does not mean B → A.

→= implies.

However, A and B do have something to do with each other. Their relationship is that A implies B and B is implied by A. And, B may even imply A, but, as given here, it does not. They have a logical relationship (in formal logic).

2)  A relationship in language between two things is not the same thing. Neither is the relationship between things as referents (real things).

The term houses (A) has something to do with construction (B).

Clearly A has something to do with B, B has something to do with A, and they both have something to do with each other. However, the relationship between them is not logical. It's a number of things that exist in reality (as referents) and some other number of things that can be linguistic. A relationship is not necessarily logical, though "a logic" can arise from a relationship.

I hope I have not got my knickers all twisted up here. :)

In other words, to have to do with something means to have a relationship with or to.